# opengl rotate position on a circle

Tags: opengl, rotation, position, geometry, orbit

I'm currently using the code from http://www.codecolony.de/opengl.htm#camera and wanted to add a function to orbit over the scene (moving the camera around the object).

I considered it like a rotation on a circle over a given center. 
It is almost working: it's rotating over the point I chose and the view is in the correct direction. The problem is that the radius is not constant and I always get closer and closer to the center.

Here is the code I write:

```
void CCamera::RotateView(GLfloat Angle, SF3dVector center) // in degree
{
    // rotate the position over the center
    Position.x = cos(Angle*PIdiv180) * (Position.x - center.x) - sin(Angle*PIdiv180) * (Position.z - center.z) + center.x;
    Position.z = sin(Angle*PIdiv180) * (Position.x - center.x) + cos(Angle*PIdiv180) * (Position.z - center.z) + center.z;

    // adjust the viewDir
    ViewDir = center - Position;

    //now compute the new RightVector (by cross product)
    RightVector = CrossProduct(&ViewDir, &UpVector);

}
```

Do you have any ideas why I(the camera) don't always stay at the same distance from the center ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you didn't provide the entire class - I'm assuming that Position is a member variable that describes the position of your camera. You are making the cardinal mistake of assuming that you've got infinite mathematical precision. You don't- since you are iterating over the position value each time, you are accumulating more and more round off error. It really does add up over a few hundred iterations. What you need to do is calculate the position fresh each time through. What you want is gluLookAt().
[gluLookatDocumentation][1]